# How can i sort an array based on the mean of each column in python?

Tags: python

```
Input:

array([[  1. ,   5. ,   1. ],
       [ 10. ,   7. ,   1.5],
       [  6.9,   5. ,   1. ],
       [ 19. ,   9. , 100. ],
       [ 11. ,  11. ,  11. ]])

Expected Output:

array([[ 19. ,   9. , 100. ],
       [ 11. ,  11. ,  11. ],
       [ 10. ,   7. ,   1.5],
       [  6.9,   5. ,   1. ],
       [  1. ,   5. ,   1. ]])

i tried doing the below:


for i in M:
    ls = i.mean()
    x = np.append(i,ls)
    print(x) #found the mean
```

After this i am unable to arrange each column based on the mean value in each row. All i can do
is to arrange each row in descending order but that is not what i wanted.

Comment: Try: `from statistics import mean; arr.sort(key=lambda x: mean(x), reverse=True)`

Comment: Your question says mean of each row. Your title says mean of each column. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
In [405]: row_idxs = np.argsort(np.mean(a * -1, axis=1))

In [406]: a[row_idxs, :]
Out[406]:
array([[ 19. ,   9. , 100. ],
       [ 11. ,  11. ,  11. ],
       [ 10. ,   7. ,   1.5],
       [  6.9,   5. ,   1. ],
       [  1. ,   5. ,   1. ]])
```

Using argsort will sort the indices. Multiplying by -1 allows you to get descending order.